# O servidor Node é a única opção para suportar nível máximo de requisições em uma aplicação?

Tags: node.js, desempenho, servidor, iis, nginx

Para um projeto de aplicação que irá precisar suportar no servidor uma quantidade imensa de requisições como por exemplo um portal de *e-commerce* no dia de *black friday* ou o servidor de uma desenvolvedora de jogos no primeiro dia do lançamento de um jogo ultra aguardado que só pode ser acessado e baixado por *login*, como por exemplo no caso do Diablo 3, o servidor Node.js seria a única opção viável para suportar o tranco sem cair? Ou o Nginx também seria uma outra alternativa viável, e o IIS estaria descartado?

Comment: Se não me engano a Uber usa `Node.js`, mas não é apenas a tecnologia utilizada no backend que irá ditar se o servidor suporta ou não suporta

Comment: não sei de onde você tirou isso.
em qualquer benchmark , o node js fica atrás de várias outras linguagens , em desempenho.
logo, um simples servidor http criado em c, já deve ser umas 50x mais rapido que algo criado em node js

Answer (score 4):

O tipo de tecnologia usada afeta um pouco a capacidade para atender a demanda, mas o que importa mesmo é a arquitetura geral, é saber o que está fazendo. O menos dos problemas costuma ser qual tecnologia vai usar.

De qualquer forma não sei porque o Node esteja sendo considerado como uma tecnologia rápida. Deve ter lido muito artigo *marketeiro* por aí. Node é lento. Claro, dá para fazer muita coisa com ele, mas tem que fazer muito direitinho para ser rápido, tem tecnologias que são muito mais rápidas até aceitam que algo não seja tão bom.

Tem um [site que faz testes independentes com várias *stacks* de tecnologias e mostra como cada um se comporta](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r16&hw=ph&test=plaintext) (fica pior quando falamos da [latência](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r16&hw=ph&test=plaintext)). Até o 11o. estão quase 100% de eficiência, incluindo aí o ASP.NET Core, ele perde apenas para *frameworks* experimentais. O NodeJS aparece em 59o. lugar com apenas 11% de eficiência. Então a decisão que a pergunta pede deve ser a oposta da proposta. Não que seja inviável usar o Node, mas é uma das opções menos viáveis.

O IIS melhorou muito, mas ele não será a melhor opção em performance nunca porque seu objetivo é dar funcionalidades diversas e não performances. Até o Nginx não é uma opção tão rápida assim. É quando comparado com servidores mais completos, mas ele tem seu custo também.

De qualquer forma a performance não é o mais importante e a decisão da melhor tecnologia passa por ampla análise e profunda observação do caso concreto, e isso só pode ser feito por alguém bastante experiente e que não seja tendencioso, além de ter todas informação na mão. Mas o mais importante é que a decisão não seja feita em cima de informações falsas.

Comment: Acho que o pessoa confunde o uso de memória por conexão com a velocidade

Comment: @Sorack talvez, mas acredito que ele perca até nisto. Não consigo imaginar como uma tecnologia baseada em JS possa ser econômica em memória. JavaScript é uma das maiores desperdiçadoras de memória que tem.